# Magento Ecommerce

Tags: magento

Does any one know of an extension or how to display the price of product's only if the customer is logged in ?

But if the customer is not logged in the price is blank ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to build a site which basically turns into a shop once a user signs up? Then I have to assume you also might want to hide the other ecommerce components such as 'add to cart' buttons, checkout button, etc.

You could hide the shop components in various places in your site design template /app/design/frontend/default/xyz/template (where 'xyz' is 'default' or your organization's design folder). Even though it's technically straight forward there are a lot of files to check this way.

What you'd have to do is find the HTML that you don't want your guests to see and enclose it like so:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
  lines of html you'd like to disable for guests
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a customer group for the logged in customer(s) and then assign pricing rules based on groups. That would allow you to show a different price for logged in customers vs general site visits.

Answer (score 1):

You can put some options like Customer Shop Status - View Shop and Prices
Customer must be approved to shop

It is recommended that Option 2 be used for the purposes of Spiders if you wish customers to login to see prices.

Answer (score 0):

Belvg has a "Private Sales" module that we use to accomplish that task.  http://store.belvg.com/private-sales.html